# Twig/PHP/Symfony nesting error - nesting level too deep

Tags: php, symfony, loops, twig

I have a (very big) twig html template, where I display a table and loop through the rows:

```
{% for assignment in assignments %}
   ...
   {% if assignment.zip.contractor1 is not null %}
       {% for priceEK in assignment.zip.contractor1.pricecontractor %}
           {% if priceEK.zip == assignment.zip %}
               {% set bookDates = date(assignment.start|date).diff(assignment.end).days + 1 %}
               {% set priceDay = 0 %}
               {% set priceSide = 0 %}
               {% if bookDates > 1 %}
                   {% set priceDay = priceEK.priceDay * (bookDates - 1) %}
                   {% set priceSide = priceEK.priceAdd * (bookDates) %}
               {% endif %}
               {% if assignment.meter == 15 %}
                   {{ (priceEK.price15 + priceDay + priceSide)|number_format(2) }}&euro;
               {% elseif assignment.meter == 20 %}
                   {{ (priceEK.price20 + priceDay + priceSide)|number_format(2) }}&euro;
               {% else %}
                   {{ (priceEK.price25 + priceDay + priceSide)|number_format(2) }}&euro;
               {% endif %}
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
    {%endif %}
```

Now this works like a charm IF, `assignment.zip.contractor1 is not null` is only true ONE TIME. If it is true a second time while looping through `assignments` it gives me the following error in my logs:

> Error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?

I assume this may be a complicated problem without knowing the database relations, please feel free letting me know what further info is needed (and how to insert here), I'll update accordingly.

//EDIT Maybe there is a way to 'reset' the nested for (`priceEK`)? `{% set priceEK = null %}` has no effect though...

//EDIT2: Found sth. else, changed all `==` to `is same as()` as described [HERE](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html). Now I can get a second loop. If I then have a third one, Firefox crashes and wants to debug the script...

//EDIT: ok, found a solution... Maybe this helps for someone else:

```
{% for pc in  assignment.zip.pricecontractor %}
    {% if pc.contractor is same as(assignment.zip.contractor1) %}
        {% set bookDates = date(assignment.start|date).diff(assignment.end).days + 1 %}
        {% set priceDay = 0 %}
        {% set priceSide = 0 %}
        {% if bookDates > 1 %}
            {% set priceDay = pc.priceDay * (bookDates - 1) %}
            {% set priceSide = pc.priceAdd * (bookDates) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if assignment.meter is same as(15) %}
            {{ (pc.price15 + priceDay + priceSide)|number_format(2) }}&euro;
        {% elseif assignment.meter is same as(20) %}
            {{ (pc.price20 + priceDay + priceSide)|number_format(2) }}&euro;
        {% else %}
            {{ (pc.price25 + priceDay + priceSide)|number_format(2) }}&euro;
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do you have xdebug enabled? Is something like [this](https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2015/11/17/symfony-xdebug-and-maximum-nesting-level-issues/)?

Comment: I dont have xDebug enabled (can't get it to work). Any other chance to see where that comes from?